# How to add text color to ListView

Tags: xamarin.android

How to add text color to ListView ?
The background is white for Layout and I need the text color to be darkgray or black.

--UI

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:background="#ffffff"    
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
android:minWidth="25px"        
android:minHeight="25px"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"        
android:layout_height="match_parent"        
android:id="@+id/ListView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

-- code :

```
       listV= FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView1);
         itemlist = new List<string>();

         itemlist.Add("item1");  
         itemlist.Add("item2");         
         itemlist.Add("item3");         
         itemlist.Add("item4");         
         itemlist.Add("item5");         
         itemlist.Add("item6");         
         itemlist.Add("item7");         
         itemlist.Add("item8");


    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemlist);

 listV.Adapter = adapter;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout file containing the textview you want with textSize, textStyle, color etc preferred by you and then use it with the ArrayAdapter.

e.g. mytextview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tview"
    android:textColor="@color/yourColor"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectgrad"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and then use it with your ArrayAdapter as usual like

```
 ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, R.layout.mytextview, itemlist);
```

Comment: use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout for this ?<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: I got this error :Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview, 
   R.id.tview, this.file) this should fix that exception.

Comment: I think you mean( this.file is my itemList). Why there is no divider or line in the ListView? How to create it? Thanks